# Html button CSS changes in Aspx

Tags: html, css, asp.net

My button CSS changes when I convert it into aspx controls.

I want Aspx Button same like HTML button.

This is what I currently have:

[image: Current result]

Below is my HTML code:

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

.login-form {
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 360px;
}

.login-form>section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.login-form>section img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.login-form>section a {
  color: #657fed;
}

.login-form h4 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #737373;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form[role=login] {
  font: 15px/2.2em Lato, serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 40px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
}

form[role=login] img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

form[role=login] input,
form[role=login] button {
  font-size: 17px;
}

form[role=login] input {
  color: #989898;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

form[role=login] input:focus {
  z-index: 1000;
}

form[role=login] input[type=email] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

form[role=login] input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /*color: #c0c0c0;*/
  color: #c0c0c0
}

form[role=login] input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

form[role=login] input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

form[role=login] input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

form[role=login] button {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #4082ef;
  border: 1px solid #3b88c3;
  background: #52a6e6;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, .3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, .3);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=1" />
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100italic,100,300italic,300,400italic,400,700italic,700,900italic,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!-- jQuery Library -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core JS -->
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 
 <section class="container">
  <section class="login-form">
  <section>
   <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
   <h4>Sign in with your Account</h4>
  </section>
  <form method="post" action="" role="login">
   <img src="images/user.png" alt="" />
   <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-lg" />
   <input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-lg" />


   <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Sign in</button>
   <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" checked /> Stay signed in
   <a href="#" class="pull-right">Need help?</a>
  </form>
  
  </section>
 </section>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put the final HTML/CSS code and not asp code ... also am sure that there is additinal CSS applied to your button even if they have the same class

Comment: no there is no additional css.I download code from http://www.bootstrapzen.com/preview/203/ , i just want that button same as it is in aspx

Comment: yes but since the two button doesn't look the same means that they don't have exactly the same CSS.

Comment: see my code please , both buttons have class="btn btn-block btn-info"

Comment: the same class doesn't mean the same CSS. One element is a button and the other one is an asp:button and both don't have the same id. That's why we need to see the final html code to see why both are different in design.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `<asp:button>` is rendering html element like `<input type="button .../>` instead of a "real" html `<button .../>`

This is why the css applied to your `<input type="button .../>` will be `form[role=login] input {...}` and not your expected one : `form[role=login] button {...}`

You have several possibilities:

1. **Use css class**: Replace `form[role=login] button` (which is a selector by element type) by `form[role=login] .btn` (selector by class name) and then do :
   `<button class="btn" .../>` and `<asp:Button CssClass="btn" />`. Drawback: `form[role=login] input` css properties not overriden will still be applied to `asp:Button`
2. **Use css element selector**: Replace `form[role=login] button {...}` by `form[role=login] button, form[role=login] input[type=button] {...}`. Drawback: Same as above, you will have to override all css properties
3. **Do not use asp:Button**: Replace `<asp:Button ....>` by `<button runat="server" ... />`. This is actually a valid server control 
   due to `runat="server"`, but you control fully the rendering as it is pure html.
   Drawback: In your code-behind, it will change the type of your control from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button` to `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton`. You might need some refactoring.

If refactoring the code behind is not a big issue, I would go for solution 3. I was never a big fan of asp controls because you can't decide what should be rendered "out of the box". With solution 3 you can write your own html, and still use some elements in code behind, plus this applies to all html elements.